# Legacy system using Oracle 8i - help faking it out

Tags: odbc, tnsnames

We have a legacy system here that can take analog ekg's over the phone and convert it to a usable format. We don't use it much any more but I cannot phase it out just yet. Problem is on Win10 64bit, the program will not find the "Service", so, I am wondering if there is a way to fake the legacy program to use a ODBC connection. The program does run, but seems to not be finding the tnsnames file or something similar. Anyone else go through this?